# Running .py file from cmd opens the python modify setup

Tags: python, cmd

I have a python file located at `myFile.py` that works perfectly fine when I run it from visual studio code or any python file launcher.

The problem is that whenever I run it using the **`python myFile.py`** command in the windows **command prompt** it just opens the ***Python Modify Setup*** (image below) instead of running the file.
***Repairing or modifying python isn't the solution.***

[image]

[Here's a video showing the problem](https://vimeo.com/739369691).

Comment: I get "Video is not rated. Log in to watch." when I try to open the video. Note that this appears to be location-specific (I'm in the UK).

Comment: you need to add python in your system virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to the python installation file `python.exe` being in the same directory as `myFile.exe`. It should be removed from that working directory.